# How to run Ubuntu without GUI in Virtual Box?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, performance, sed, distro-recommendation

I have a Windows XP laptop, in which I run VirtualBox with the latest Ubuntu, my hardware is little old, so running the latest version of Ubuntu inside Virtual box is kind of a hassle, very slow performances, even if all i'm doing is running the terminal and practicing Linux commands !

I tried DSL (Damn Small Linux) with my VirtualBox, very small distro (50 MB), I am satisfied with how faster is my system now, but I miss Ubuntu, moreover, DSL is missing too many commands, such as sed an many others that I can't remember.

Is it possible to run Ubuntu just in console mode, no GUI or minimum GUI...no nice effects no fancy graphics? A link / tutorial would be much appreciated.

Comment: If sed etc. is the only issue, it seems like you can use APT on DSL: http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/wiki/enabling_apt.html
After that, you just need to apt-get install sed

Comment: [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/screenshots/) and [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) are lightweight GUI desktops. If you want a GUI free version you could consider the Server version but that includes other things you may not want or take a look at Ubuntu Minimal [download is here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and there is an how to [here](http://maketecheasier.com/install-a-minimal-ubuntu-on-old-laptop/2012/02/24) just install the bits you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way is to install [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) inside VirtualBox, it cames with no GUI by default, just command line.

If you change your mind and need a GUI, try [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/),it uses LXDE a quite light GUI.

Comment: you mean install ? i do not want to install anything now, just because my system is old, and i still need my XP for school homework...i'm planning an upgrade thou :) hardware first, then UBUNTU next

Comment: I think he means installing Ubuntu Server into the VM...

Comment: ok, you guys are awesome, too many answers unfortunately i cannot up vote everybody :) Thanks a lot

Comment: Ubuntu Server == 800 MB. LOL small distro))

Answer (score 7):

If you have installed ubuntu on vbox than run ubuntu and press right-ctrl + F2

By doing this you will enter terminal mode and to come back anytime to GUI PRESS right-ctrl + F7

By doing this i think you dont even need to install new ubuntu you can run your current ubuntu without graphics and can practice

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing Xubuntu.

Comment: how is it different ? i'm total beginner, bear with me :)

Comment: It just ships with a different Desktop (GUI). Xubuntu comes with XFCE, which is more "light weight" than unity. But I'm not sure if its going to be that much faster.

Comment: @user68186 Xubuntu potentially meets the description "...or minimum GUI...no nice effects no fancy graphics." It's possible to get a lot more minimal than Xubuntu, and in fact there's no need to have a GUI running at all, so this is probably not a very good answer (and might even be considered wrong), but *it is still an answer.* This answer should be longer and contain more explanation, but [it's still better as an answer than a comment](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2281/please-stop-posting-half-answers-and-dumb-advice-as-comments).

Comment: i will go for XUBUNTU tonight after work...hopefully everything will be ok, thanks

Comment: @joe Please remember that you can run Ubuntu with no GUI at all, and that if you want a full-featured GUI, Lubuntu is lighter-weight than Xubuntu.